# cscope's bug? cscope can't find the definition of a function with a function pointer argument

Tags: cscope

```
//main.c  
#include "stdio.h"
void f(){
    printf("Welcome to emacs's world!");
    return;
}
void call_f(void (*f)()){
    (*f)();
    return;
}
void main(){
    call_f(f);
    return;
}
```

I use cscope to find the definition of function "call_f", but have no result, the cscope can't find the definition of "call_f".
I change the argument type of function "call_f" to another type except for a function pointer.

```
#include "stdio.h"
void f(){
    printf("Welcome to emacs's world!");
    return;
}
void call_f(/* void (*f)() */void){
//    (*f)();
    f();
    return;
}
void main(){
//    call_f(f);
    call_f(void);
    return;
}
```

Then cscope can find the definition of function "call_f".
Is that a bug?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a bug. Cscope doesn't implement a full C language parser. Instead it just uses a scanner with a lot of quirks.

For example, cscope also isn't able to recognize function calls/declarations if the [opening argument bracket is on the next line](https://sourceforge.net/p/cscope/bugs/119/) like this:

```
fn_foo
    (arg1, arg2);
```

The bug you found is even [documented in cscope's man page](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html):

> Nor does it recognize function  definitions  with  a  function  pointer
>   argument
>
> ```
>     ParseTable::Recognize(int startState, char *pattern,
>       int finishState, void (*FinalAction)(char *))
>     {
>       ...
>     }
> ```